# Agenda job processing time slower than expected when running multiple jobs concurrently, causing backlog - any solutions?

Tags: message-queue, agenda, bullmq

I'm using the Agenda library for job scheduling in my Node.js application. However, I'm experiencing some unexpected behavior where jobs are scheduled for the wrong time, or not at all when I run a lot of jobs. For example, I use job.now() to schedule a job immediately, but it gets scheduled for the day after. Additionally, when I run a large number of jobs, the library seems to get confused and doesn't execute some of the jobs as expected.

Has anyone experienced similar issues with Agenda? Is this a known issue with the library, or is there something I could be doing wrong in my implementation? Would it be more reliable to switch to another library like BullMQ? Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated